# Codeignitor code gives undefined property error on live server but not on localhost

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using Codeignitor code, the code works fine and show output on localhost fine but the same code when run on live server gives an error as:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$data
Filename: controllers/Welcome.php
Line Number: 49
Backtrace:
File: /application/controllers/Welcome.php
Line: 49
Function: _error_handler
```

The code is as follows

1. application/controllers/Welcome.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()  || empty($this->session->name)) 
        {
            redirect('/login');
        }
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('BasicModel', 'basic');
        $this->load->model('LabelModel', 'label');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        //if candidate, go to basic details
        if($this->ion_auth->in_group('candidate'))
        {
            redirect('basic/edit/'.$this->session->basic_id);
        }
        if($_SESSION['org']==1)
        {
            //Get MIS count
            $this->getMISCount();
        }
        else
        {
            //Get Vericraft count without integration
            $this->getCount();
        }
        
        if($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
        {
            //Get Client list
            $this->getClientList();
        }
        else if($this->ion_auth->in_group('dev'))
        {
            $this->getDevData();
        }
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $this->data);
    }
    public function candidate()
    {
        $this->data['label_data'] = $this->label->view_label();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, CONCAT(CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fname,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS fname,' ',CAST(AES_DECRYPT(mname,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS mname, ' ',CAST(AES_DECRYPT(sname,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS sname) as name,Refno, gender, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(dob,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS dob, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(email,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS email, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(contact,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS contact, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(empid,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS empid, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(location,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS location, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(report,'".encrypted_key."') AS CHAR) AS report FROM basic WHERE user_id =".$this->session->user_id);
        $this->data['show_data'] = $query->result_array();
        
        //to get total document label
        $label_query = $this->db->select('id, label')->from('components')->get();
        $this->data['labels'] = array_column($label_query->result_array(), 'label');

        $query =$this->db->select('COUNT(vlink.id) as num_doc, vlink.file_name, vlink.created_at, vlink.updated_at, vlabel.label')
        ->from('document_links as vlink')
        ->join('components as vlabel', 'vlink.comp_id = vlabel.id', 'full outer')
        ->where('vlink.user_id', $this->session->user_id)
        ->group_by('vlink.comp_id')
        ->get();
        $this->data['count_data'] = array_column($query->result_array(), 'num_doc', 'label');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Details updated successfully!');
        return redirect($this->agent->referrer());
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->ion_auth->logout();
        redirect('login/index', 'refresh');
    }

    public function getMISCount()
    {
        if($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
        {
            //MIS Total cases
            $this->data['mis_total']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM ichek_database WHERE  ichek_database.Refno NOT LIKE '%test%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%';")->row();

                //MIS Pending Cases
            $this->data['mis_pending']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as pending FROM ichek_database WHERE  ichek_database.Refno NOT LIKE '%test%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND (ichek_database.reportdate='' OR ichek_database.reportdate=0 OR ichek_database.reportdate IS NULL);")->row();
                //MIS Green Cases
            $this->data['mis_green']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as green FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno NOT LIKE '%test%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND ichek_database.reportdate!='' AND ichek_database.reportdate!=0 AND ichek_database.reportdate IS NOT NULL AND (ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='' OR ichek_remark.negdedupcolor IS NULL OR ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='Green');")->row();

                //MIS Amber Cases
            $this->data['mis_amber']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as yellow FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno NOT LIKE '%test%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND (ichek_database.reportdate!='' AND ichek_database.reportdate!=0 AND ichek_database.reportdate IS NOT NULL) AND ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='Amber';")->row();

                //MIS Red Cases
            $this->data['mis_red']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as red FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno NOT LIKE '%test%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND (ichek_database.reportdate!='' AND ichek_database.reportdate!=0 AND ichek_database.reportdate IS NOT NULL) AND ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='Red';")->row();

                //MIS Stop Cases
            $this->data['mis_stop']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as stop FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno NOT LIKE '%test%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending LIKE '%stop%';")->row();
        }
        else if($this->ion_auth->in_group('client'))
        {
            //MIS Total cases
            $this->data['mis_total']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM ichek_database WHERE  ichek_database.Refno LIKE '%".$_SESSION['client_code']."%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%';")->row();

                //MIS Pending Cases
            $this->data['mis_pending']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as pending FROM ichek_database WHERE  ichek_database.Refno LIKE '%".$_SESSION['client_code']."%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND (ichek_database.reportdate='' OR ichek_database.reportdate=0 OR ichek_database.reportdate IS NULL);")->row();

                //MIS Green Cases
            $this->data['mis_green']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as green FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno LIKE '%".substr($_SESSION['client_code'], 0, 4)."%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND (ichek_database.reportdate!='' AND ichek_database.reportdate!=0 AND ichek_database.reportdate IS NOT NULL) AND (ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='' OR ichek_remark.negdedupcolor IS NULL OR ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='Green');")->row();

                //MIS Amber Cases
            $this->data['mis_amber']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as yellow FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno LIKE '%".substr($_SESSION['client_code'], 0, 4)."%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND (ichek_database.reportdate!='' AND ichek_database.reportdate!=0 AND ichek_database.reportdate IS NOT NULL) AND ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='Amber';")->row();

                //MIS Red Cases
            $this->data['mis_red']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as red FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno LIKE '%".substr($_SESSION['client_code'], 0, 4)."%' AND (ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%stop%') AND (ichek_database.reportdate!='' AND ichek_database.reportdate!=0 AND ichek_database.reportdate IS NOT NULL) AND ichek_remark.negdedupcolor='Red';")->row();

                //MIS Stop Cases
            $this->data['mis_stop']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as stop FROM ichek_database INNER JOIN ichek_remark ON ichek_database.Refno=ichek_remark.Refno WHERE  ichek_database.Refno LIKE '%".substr($_SESSION['client_code'], 0, 4)."%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending LIKE '%stop%';")->row();
        }   
    }

    public function getCount()
    {
        if($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
        {
            $query=$this->db->query("select count(vbasic.id) as num, vbasic.status from basic as vbasic inner join users on vbasic.user_id=users.id WHERE users.org=".$this->session->org." group by vbasic.status;");
        }
        else if($this->ion_auth->in_group('client'))
        {
            $query=$this->db->query("select count(vbasic.id) as num, vbasic.status from basic as vbasic inner join users on vbasic.user_id=users.id where vbasic.Refno like '%".$this->session->client_code."%' and users.org=".$this->session->org." group by vbasic.status;");
        }
        else if($this->ion_auth->in_group('dev'))
        {
            $query=$this->db->query("select count(vbasic.id) as num, vbasic.status from basic as vbasic inner join users on vbasic.user_id=users.id WHERE users.org=".$this->session->org." group by vbasic.status;");
        }

        $this->data['countData'] = array_column($query->result_array(), 'num', 'status');
    }

    public function getClientList()
    {
        if($_SESSION['org']==1)
        {
            $this->data['mis_clients']=$this->load->database('mis',TRUE)->query("SELECT DISTINCT(temp.full_name) as full_name, temp.client FROM temp INNER JOIN ichek_basic ON temp.client=ichek_basic.client INNER JOIN ichek_database ON ichek_basic.Refno=ichek_database.Refno WHERE temp.client NOT LIKE '%test%' AND ichek_database.reasonpending NOT LIKE '%dup%' ORDER BY temp.full_name")->result();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['clients'] = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(users.company), users.client_code FROM `users` INNER JOIN users_groups on users.id=users_groups.user_id WHERE users.org=".$this->session->org." AND users_groups.group_id=2 order by users.company asc")->result();
        }
    }

    public function getDevData()
    {
        $this->data['totalActiveOrg'] = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(org)) as num FROM `users` WHERE org!=0")->row();

        $this->data['totalUsers'] = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as num FROM users_groups WHERE group_id!=4")->row();

        $this->data['totalCases'] = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as num FROM basic")->row();

        $this->data['totalFilesUploaded'] = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(document_links.id) as num FROM `document_links` INNER JOIN users on document_links.user_id=users.id")->row();

        $this->data['fileName'] = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(file_name) FROM `document_links`")->result();

        $this->data['organizations']=$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(organization.org_name),organization.id from organization INNER JOIN users on organization.id=users.org WHERE users.org!=0 ORDER BY organization.org_name")->result();
    }
}
?>
```

2. application/views/welcome_message.php

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('layouts/header.php'); 
$this->load->view('layouts/navbar.php'); 
?>
<!-- page content -->

<?PHP 
if(!($this->ion_auth->in_group('dev')))
{ 
    ?>
    <div class="right_col" role="main">
        <!--******************** START SESSION SETFLASH MESSAGES *****************************-->
        <?php 
        if($this->session->flashdata('message'))
        {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message')?>
            </div>
            <?php 
        } 
        ?>
        <!--************************* END SESSION SETFLASH MESSAGES   ************************-->
        <!-- top tiles -->
        <?php
        $stopcase = $inprocess = $green = $red = $yellow  = 0;

        if($_SESSION['org']==1)
        {
        
            $green= $green+$mis_green->green;
            $red= $red+$mis_red->red;
            $yellow= $yellow+$mis_amber->yellow;
            $stopcase= $stopcase+$mis_stop->stop;
            $inprocess= $inprocess+$mis_pending->pending;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($countData as $status => $num)
            {
                if($status == 'inprocess') 
                {
                    $inprocess = (int)$num;
                }
                if($status == 'green')
                { 
                    $green = (int)$num;
                }
                if($status == 'red') 
                {
                    $red = (int)$num;
                }
                if($status == 'yellow') 
                {
                    $yellow = (int)$num;
                }
                if($status == 'stopcase') 
                {
                    $stopcase = (int)$num;
                }
            }
        }

        $total = $inprocess + $green + $red + $yellow + $stopcase;
        ?>
        <div class="row tile_count text-center">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
                <a href="<?=site_url('candidate/casetable?total');?>">
                    <span class="count_top blue"><i class="fa fa-users blue"></i> Total Case</span>
                    <div class="count blue"><?=$total;?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
                <a href="<?=site_url('candidate/casetable?inprocess');?>">
                    <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> In Process</span>
                    <div class="count"><?=$inprocess;?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/casetable?green') ?>">
                    <span class="count_top green"><i class="fa fa-user-circle green"></i> Green</span>
                    <div class="count green"><?php echo $green; ?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/casetable?yellow') ?>">
                    <span class="count_top yellow"><i class="fa fa-user-circle yellow"></i> Amber</span>
                    <div class="count yellow"><?php echo $yellow; ?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/casetable?red') ?>">
                    <span class="count_top red"><i class="fa fa-user-circle red"></i> Red</span>
                    <div class="count red"><?php echo $red; ?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--Stop Case//-->
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/casetable?stopcase') ?>">
                    <span class="count_top red"><i class="fa fa-user-circle red"></i> Stop Case</span>
                    <div class="count red"><?php echo $stopcase; ?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /top tiles -->
        <?PHP 
        if(($this->ion_auth->in_group('client')))
        {
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="dashboard_graph">

                        <div class="row x_title">
                            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div id="donut"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bg-white">
                            <div class="x_title">
                                <h3>BGV Performance</h3>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php

                            $transition1 = $total != 0 ? ($total/$total * 100): 0;
                            $transition2 = $total != 0 ? ($inprocess/$total * 100): 0;
                            $transition3 = $total != 0 ? ($green/$total * 100): 0;
                            $transition4 = $total != 0 ? ($yellow/$total * 100): 0;
                            $transition5 = $total != 0 ? ($red/$total * 100): 0;
                            $transition6 = $total != 0 ? ($stopcase/$total * 100): 0;

                            ?>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                                <div>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/index') ?>" class="text-primary">Total Case</a></p>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="<?php  echo $transition1 ?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/index?case=inprocess') ?>" class="text-primary">In Process</a></p>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-default" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="<?php echo $transition2  ?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/index?case=green') ?>" class="text-primary"> Green</a></p>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="<?php  echo $transition3 ?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                                <div>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/index?case=yellow') ?>" class="text-primary"> Amber</a></p>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-yellow" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="<?php echo $transition4 ?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/index?case=red') ?>" class="text-primary">Red</a></p>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-red" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal=" <?php  echo $transition5 ?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('candidate/index?case=stopcase') ?>" class="text-primary">Stop Case</a></p>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="progress progress_sm" style="width: 100%;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-red" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal=" <?php  echo $transition6 ?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?PHP 
        }
        if(($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin')))
        {
            if($_SESSION['org']!=1)
            {
                foreach($clients as $row2)
                {
                    $company_name=$row2->company;
                    $client_code=$row2->client_code;
                    $query_client_details=$this->db->query("select count(vbasic.id) as num, vbasic.status from basic as vbasic inner join users on vbasic.user_id=users.id where vbasic.Refno like '%".$client_code."%' and users.org=".$this->session->org." group by vbasic.status");
                    $res_count=array_column($query_client_details->result_array(), 'num', 'status');
                    $stopcase = $inprocess = $green = $red = $yellow  = 0;
                    
                    foreach($res_count as $key => $data)
                    {
                        if($key == 'inprocess') $inprocess = (int)$data;
                        if($key == 'green') $green = (int)$data;
                        if($key == 'red') $red = (int)$data;
                        if($key == 'yellow') $yellow = (int)$data;
                        if($key == 'stopcase') $stopcase = (int)$data;
                    }
                    $total = $inprocess + $green + $red + $yellow + $stopcase;
                    ?>
                    <div class="row"><br>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="dashboard_graph">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bg-white">
                                    <div class="x_title">
                                        <h3><?PHP echo $company_name; ?></h3>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                    $transition1 = $total != 0 ? ($total/$total * 100): 0;
                                    $transition2 = $total != 0 ? ($inprocess/$total * 100): 0;
                                    $transition3 = $total != 0 ? ($green/$total * 100): 0;
                                    $transition4 = $total != 0 ? ($yellow/$total * 100): 0;
                                    $transition5 = $total != 0 ? ($red/$total * 100): 0;
                                    $transition6 = $total != 0 ? ($stopcase/$total * 100): 0;
                                    ?>
```

Please help me why am I getting an undefined property error on live server and not on localhost. please someone help solving this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used $this->data but u have not defined it

```
$this->load->view('welcome_message', $this->data);
```

define it in constructor like this :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()  || empty($this->session->name)) 
        {
            redirect('/login');
        }
        $this->data = [];
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('BasicModel', 'basic');
        $this->load->model('LabelModel', 'label');
    }
```

for your new error :
you are using $mis_green  as object

```
 $green= $green+$mis_green->green;
```

may be its an array kindly check it if its an array use it like this :

```
 $green= $green+$mis_green['green'];
 $red= $red+$mis_red['red']; 
 $yellow= $yellow+$mis_amber['yellow'];
 $stopcase= $stopcase+$mis_stop['stop']; 
 $inprocess= $inprocess+$mis_pending['pending'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have used $this->data but u have not defined it